# BigDecimal scientific notation String and normal String

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I have this piece of code

```
BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal("8000000");
BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal("80e5");
System.out.println("a equal b? " +a.compareTo(b));

BigDecimal resultA = a.divide(new BigDecimal("1000"), BigDecimal.ROUND_UP);
BigDecimal resultB = b.divide(new BigDecimal("1000"), BigDecimal.ROUND_UP);

System.out.println(resultA.compareTo(resultB));
System.out.println(resultA);
System.out.println(resultB);
```

Result

```
a equal b? 0
-1
8000
1E+5
```

I don't get it? why a `8000000/1000`and round up different from `80e5/1000` and round up ? And java said at first time `a` `compare` to `b` is 0 (equal?)

Comment: The question can be boiled down to *"Why does `80e5` divided by `1000` equal `100000` rather than `8000`?"*. The compareTo and the first BigDecimal is unnecessary. It's clear where the problem lies.

Comment: @preciousbetine With `compareTo()`, `0` means equal.

Comment: @Gendarme but `80e5/1000` is `8000` (`System.out.println(b.divide(new BigDecimal("1000")));`), the problem comes when divide and round up?

Comment: @Gendarme: I think the introduction with *compareTo()* helped clarify that while `8000000` and `80e5` *compare as equal*, when divided by the same small number, `1000`, they don't produce the same result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `divide` method you're using sets the scale of the result to the scale of the original object:

[BigDecimal.divide(BigDecimal, int)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#divide-java.math.BigDecimal-int-)

> Returns a BigDecimal whose value is (this / divisor), and whose scale is this.scale(). If rounding must be performed to generate a result with the given scale, the specified rounding mode is applied.

Since you create `b` from "80e5" its scale is -5, and `divide` has to round its result up to 1e+5:

```
jshell> var b = new BigDecimal("80e5");
b ==> 8.0E+6

jshell> b.scale()
$4 ==> -5

jshell> var c = b.divide(new BigDecimal("1000"), BigDecimal.ROUND_UP);
c ==> 1E+5

jshell> c.scale()
$6 ==> -5
```

To solve this, you can set the scale you want for the result when dividing:

```
jshell> b.divide(new BigDecimal("1000"), 0, BigDecimal.ROUND_UP);
$7 ==> 8000
```

Comment: Oh, I didn't know java get `80e5`'s scale is `-5`. haha, nice explanation sir.